# NSURLCache alternative in Android

Tags: android, ios, caching

I have custom caching engine in my iOS application.

```
AFURLCache* urlCache = [[[AFURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:@""] autorelease];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:urlCache];
```

Now thinking of the Android version.

What would be the approach there? Is there a way to set in-house custom handling of HTTP requests?

Answer (score 0):

Android alternative for NSURLCache is HttpResponseCache.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html

This class supports HttpURLConnection and HttpsURLConnection; there is no platform-provided cache for DefaultHttpClient or AndroidHttpClient.